# Is it necessary to refresh the chef vault everytime we regenerate keys?

Tags: chef-infra, knife, chef-vault

I am admin of a chef vault. I have regenerated my key recently. Now when I try to access the secrets  it shows error saying unable to decrypt the secrets and I need to get the vault refresh done by an admin. I checked with another administrator  but he is also facing the same issue.

**ChefVault::Exceptions::SecretDecryption: VAULT/ITEM is encrypted for you, but your private key failed to decrypt the contents. (if you regenerated your client key, have an administrator of the vault run 'knife vault refresh')**

I wanted to know if I can recover the secrets without the need to refresh the vault ? I don't have the secret values stored anywhere else to be able to create a new vault.
Please advise.

Tried to refresh the vault using

**knife vault refresh VAULT ITEM**

but getting the same error. There are no other admins who can access the vault to be able to refresh it.

As an alternative can I get the decrypted secrets from one of the VMs (client) which is bootstrapped from the chef server?

Note: I am new to chef and don't have much knowledge on the available options. But this is very urgent.kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You indeed need to refresh, the vault system works with a symmetric encryption key which is in turn encrypted with your public key for you.

So to decrypt a secret you need to first to decrypt the vault key with your private key.

You can check who's in the admin list with `knife databag show <vault> <item>_keys`.

You should be able to just edit this databag item to add a node to the admins array and then run the refresh command on the node itself (and you should probably do a `knife vault rotate <vault> <item>` too).